# Magento 2 multiple website with subdomain

Tags: magento2, multidomain, multi-website

I have created multiple web site in magento 2 and also created the sub domain for it.
Hear my sub domain look like this

> 1.www.a.example.com
>   2.www.b.example.com

where a and b represent each country how can i point this to my website

Comment: Take a look here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html